# Calendar in Java... I get the same result for two different values

Tags: java, calendar

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long now = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    int year = 2014;
    int month = 3;
    int date = 8;
    cal.set(year, month - 1, date);
    long dday = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    long count = (dday - now) / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    System.out.println((dday - now));
    System.out.println(count);
```

This code figures out how many days between now and a date.
However, I get the same result for Mar. 8 and Mar. 9.
Please help!
Thank you in advance.

---

More detailed source code example, by Basil Bourque.

```java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
long nowInMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

cal.set( 2014, Calendar.MARCH, 8 );  // March 8, 2014   // year, month, day
long march_8_2014_inMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

cal.set( 2014,  Calendar.MARCH, 9 );  // March 9, 2014   // year, month, day
long march_9_2014_inMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

long daysTil8th = ( march_8_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) / ( 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60 );
long daysTil9th = ( march_9_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) / ( 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60 );

System.out.println( "( march_8_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) in artificial days: " + daysTil8th + ", in milliseconds: " + ( march_8_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) );
System.out.println( "( march_9_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) in artificial days: " + daysTil9th + ", in milliseconds: " + ( march_9_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) );

System.out.println( "( march_9_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) - ( march_8_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ): " + ( ( march_9_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) - ( march_8_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) ) ) ;
System.out.println( "( march_9_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) - ( march_8_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ): " + ( ( march_9_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) - ( march_8_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) ) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) ) ;
```

When run in Seattle, Java 7, Mac OS X 10.8.5 at 2013-11-20T17:35:01.119-08:00 (Pacific Standard Time)…

```
( march_8_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) in artificial days: 108, in milliseconds: 9331200000
( march_9_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) in artificial days: 108, in milliseconds: 9414000000
( march_9_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) - ( march_8_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ): 82800000
( march_9_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) - ( march_8_2014_inMillis - nowInMillis ) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ): 23
```

NOTE: For my time zone, [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) begins 2:00 AM on Sunday, March 9, 2014.

QUESTION: Why `108` in both lines of output above? The answer is DST, but how exactly?

Comment: which two values are identical?  I ran your code and I don't see any identical values.

Comment: I ran this code on Eclipse, and I get 108 days for both Mar. 8 and Mar. 9.

Comment: @user3015561: you didn't happen to do this right around midnight your time, did you?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I tried it at around 3 pm. I just tried it again, but I get the same result.

Comment: check if cal.getTimeInMillis() fetches the correct date.

Comment: So much for my potentially super awesome answer. I just ran it as well I have 107 & 108 as well. What timezone are you in?

Comment: I am in CST. What's wrong with my Eclipse?? I tried it on my laptop and desktop, but I get 108 days for Mar. 8 and Mar. 9.

Comment: Internally everything's UTC. Right now UTC is 00:10...

Comment: Are you sure you are saving the file after changing it ?

Comment: Try `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));` What does this yield?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If he is getting 108 days for march 8th, I dont think its a system related issue.

Comment: @Adarsh Yes... it is so weird.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thanks, but I get the same result.

Comment: Do you have any other code other than this that might interfere?

Comment: The thing that I don't understand is I get the same result on both my laptop and desktop.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jim Garrison said in [his correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20110638/642706), your integer-based math `(1000 * 24 * 60 * 60)` assumes 24-hours in a day. Not true for those of us in a time zone with the irrational practice of [Daylight Saving Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (DST). Between the 8th and 9th in United States’ time zones is 23 hours, not 24.

Lessons learned:

- Never do your own Date and Time math.
- Never use java.util.Date & .Calendar bundled in Java.
- Always use a decent library such as [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) in Java 8.

Here's the same problem solved in Java 7 with Joda-Time 2.3, and correct output.

```
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

// Using US west coast time zone because March 9, 2014 at 02:00 is the start of DST Daylight Saving Time.
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone californiaTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");

org.joda.time.DateTime now = new org.joda.time.DateTime(californiaTimeZone);

// Note the arbitrary choice of times (14 & 21 hours) assigned to new DateTimes.
org.joda.time.DateTime march_8_2014 = new org.joda.time.DateTime( 2014, 3, 8, 14, 0);
org.joda.time.DateTime march_9_2014 = new org.joda.time.DateTime( 2014, 3, 9, 21, 0);

int daysUntil8th = org.joda.time.Days.daysBetween( now , march_8_2014 ).getDays();
int daysUntil9th = org.joda.time.Days.daysBetween( now , march_9_2014 ).getDays();

// If you want whole days, call 'withTimeAtStartOfDate()' method.
// Don't get clever with trying to set a midnight time. Not every day in every time zone has a midnight.
int daysUntil8thStarts = org.joda.time.Days.daysBetween( now , march_8_2014.withTimeAtStartOfDay() ).getDays();
int daysUntil9thStarts = org.joda.time.Days.daysBetween( now , march_9_2014.withTimeAtStartOfDay() ).getDays();

System.out.println("Now in 'America/Los_Angeles' (Pacific Standard Time): " + now );

System.out.println("Days until " +  march_8_2014 + ": " + daysUntil8th );
System.out.println("Days until " + march_9_2014 + ": " + daysUntil9th );

System.out.println("Days until March 8, 2014 starts: " + daysUntil8thStarts );
System.out.println("Days until March 9, 2014 starts: " + daysUntil9thStarts );
```

When run…

```
Now in 'America/Los_Angeles' (Pacific Standard Time): 2013-11-20T18:25:06.424-08:00
Days until 2014-03-08T14:00:00.000-08:00: 107
Days until 2014-03-09T21:00:00.000-07:00: 109
Days until March 8, 2014 starts: 107
Days until March 9, 2014 starts: 108
```

**NOTE:** Time of day affects the count of days. Notice 107 & 109 versus 107 & 108, a *two* day difference versus *one* day difference.

Answer (score 3):

March 9th is the day on which DST will switch in 2014.  So, the calculation is right, the difference for March 9th is 108 days 23 hours, which rounds to 108 days.

Comment: What causes the difference between his calculation and my local one with identical code?

Comment: WE all got 108 for March 9th. And 107 for March 8th. He was getting 108 for both. How is that possible ?

Comment: I too see the problem: I'm getting 108 for both, here in Seattle. See my source code appended to question.

Comment: The answer is Daylight Savings Time, but I'm not sure how exactly. What time of day does Calendar class use? See my revised code on your question. 23 hour difference must mean DST happening.

Comment: long count = ((dday - now) / (1000));
  if (count % 86400 == 0) System.out.println(count / 86400);
  else System.out.println(count / 86400 + 1);

Comment: The way the code was originally written the two dates had exactly the same time of day, which was around 1700 CST.  Since DST starts at 0200 on March 9th, the hour-of-day 1700 on March 9th represents 108 days 23 hours from the first timestamp. Truncation on integer division caused this to come out 108.

Comment: @user3015561 The real solution is to use Joda-Time, not do your own Date & Time math. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20111141/642706) for example source code.

Comment: Actually, no, the real solution is to understand the effects of integer division and allow for the possibility that a day isn't 24 hours long, as happens twice a year in a large part of the world.